# Error in Google App Engine python imports for CourseBuilder

Tags: google-app-engine, markup

I am trying to set up a Google CourseBuilder site on a RHEL server. I follow the instructions [here](https://code.google.com/p/course-builder/wiki/GetCode#5._Start_the_development_server) and get the server running. However every request errors out with the following message. I have not changed any configuration from the provided package and a similar approach worked on Windows 8.

```
ERROR    2013-03-07 16:05:10,337 dev_appserver_import_hook.py:1251] Third party package markupsafe was enabled in app.yaml but not found on import. You may have to download and install it.
INFO     2013-03-07 16:05:10,412 dev_appserver.py:3104] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 -
```

What is strange is that the markupsafe package is already in .../google_appengine/lib/markupsafe-0.15

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

In the app.yaml file add the `markupsafe` library. For example:

```
libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
- name: markupsafe
  version: latest
```